# Angularjs Pagination directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

i am trying to write a directive to generate pagination links using the concept used in [a simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.com/simplePagination.js/)
the prev and next links are the only links being generated and clicking them generates an error:

```js
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kelvo/zZURe/

### Edit 1

got the rest of the links to show but the bi-directional binding '=' does not seem to work.

here is the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kelvo/zZURe/7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were updating a piece of code outside of angular and needed to let angular know to reprocess itself.

```
        $scope.selectPage = function(pageIndex) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageIndex;
            $scope.draw();
            $scope.$apply();                        
        }
```

I added the $scope.$apply(); and now the currentPage updates correctly in the input. Here are the docs on the $apply method: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/zZURe/14/